# graphics drawxxx method does not work

Tags: java, swing

I am new to graphics.
I got this code from open source.It should paint String "HEeelo" on jframe,but it does not.Can anyone explain why it is not working properly and the principle of paint method?Why should it edit JFrame as it is just method which is not even called from main?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class view extends JFrame{

    public view(){
        this.setSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
       g.drawString("heello", 10, 10);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        new view();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of that tutorial, that is not the way to do painting.

First the basic problems are that you should always invoke super.paint(...) when overriding a method. Secondly the text won't show because it is being painted under the title bar. You need to increase the y offset:

```
super.paint(g);
g.drawString("heello", 10, 40);
```

> and the principle of paint method

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do this. Basically you override the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame. You should not do custom painting on a frame directly.